# What is the difference between eav/attribute and eav/entity_attribute?

Tags: eav, attribute-set

Looking at **eav_setup file** and trying to understand the difference between the **`eav/attribute`** and **`eav/entity_attribute`** table.

If I have to guess,

> `eav/attribute` is the entity that represents the concept of attribute
>
> `eav/entity_attribute` is also an attribute which additionally carries the concept of

- attribute (the actual attribute)
- entity type that I can describe (entity_type_id)
- attribute set that I belong  (attribute_set_id)
- attribute group that I belong (attribute_group_id)

I'm not sure about the `entity_type_id`

When I create the attribute in Magento admin, I create the raw `eav/attribute`.
When I assign it to attribute set in the admin, I create the `eav/entity_attribute`. (but where does `entity_type_id` come from?)

Above statements are pure guesswork, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

1. Entity - Entity actually refers to data item.
   e.g. catalog_category_entity, catalog_product_entity, customer_entity,
   customer_address_entity
2. Attribute - Attribute refers to the different attributes of an Entity.
   e.g. entity_type_id.
3. eav_attribute - In this table all attributes for all the entities are stored.
4. eav_entity_attribute - This table contains all the relations between an attribute, its attribute group and attribute set.

Answer (score -1):

entity_type_id comes from eav_entity_type table. This table contains the information regarding the entities.

entity_type_id  entity_type_code
1   customer
2   customer_address
3   catalog_category
4   catalog_product
5   order
6   invoice
7   creditmemo
8   shipment